# Git: Alias error: Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

Tags: git, git-config, git-alias

I created a git command that shows me the diff between the HEAD and the last Git-SVN commit.

Git is the command

```
git diff `git log --grep git-svn-id | grep commit | sed "s/commit //g" | head -1` HEAD
```

And I wanted to make an alias for it and I did it like this:

```
git config --global alias.diffsvn 'diff `git log --grep git-svn-id | grep commit | sed "s/commit //g" | head -1` HEAD'
```

but when I run `git diffsvn` and have the output of that command but I get

> fatal: ambiguous argument '`git': unknown revision or path not in the
>   working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   'git  [...] -- [...]'

How can I make this alias work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is you need to add a `!git`, in front of the diff, to tell git it is a shell command.  So this:

```
git config --global alias.diffsvn '!git diff `git log --grep git-svn-id | grep commit | sed "s/commit //g" | head -1` HEAD'
```

I suggest this instead:

```
git config --global alias.diffsvn '!git diff `git log --grep git-svn-id -1 | sed -n "s/commit //p"` HEAD'
```